# Implementing and calling a static method in a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, static

My code is as below:

**Interpolation.h**

```
#ifndef INTERPOLATOR
#define INTERPOLATOR

#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class Interpolator
{
    public:
        static T InterpolateVector(const std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> & Vector, T At);

    private:
        static T GetBasisValue(T x);
};

template <class T>
T Interpolator::InterpolateVector(const std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> & Vector, T At) // Line #22
{
    // ...
}   // Line #25

// ...

#endif  // INTERPOLATOR
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include "Interpolator.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::pair<float, float>> Measurements;
    Measurements.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 80.8));
    Measurements.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 80.4));
    Measurements.push_back(std::make_pair(3, 80.1));
    Measurements.push_back(std::make_pair(4, 79.6));

    float y2 = Interpolator<float>::InterpolateVector(Measurements, 2.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

When I build this code, I get the following error messages:

> C:...\Interpolator.h; Line #22
>   error C2955: 'Interpolator' : use of class
>   template requires template argument
>   list
>
> C:...\Interpolator.h; Line #25
>   error C2244:
>   'Interpolator::InterpolateVector' :
>   unable to match function definition to
>   an existing declaration

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

(IDE: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written in the error message: `'Interpolator' : use of class template requires template argument list`

You should write:

```
template <class T>
T Interpolator<T>::InterpolateVector(const std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> & Vector, T At) // Line #22
{
    // ...
}   // Line #25
```

Comment: It worked. Many thanks. Is everything else alright in the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef INTERPOLATOR
#define INTERPOLATOR

#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class Interpolator
{
    public:
        static T InterpolateVector(const std::vector<std::pair<T, T> > & Vector, T At);

    private:
        static T GetBasisValue(T x);
};

template <class T>
T Interpolator <T> ::InterpolateVector(const std::vector<std::pair<T, T> > & Vector, T At) // Line #22
{
    // ...
}   // Line #25
```